Recognize geometric pattern in natural form
UPDATED
Although my question arises from biology, it’s about geometry.
I’m interested in various natural structures: fractals, packing, hyperuniformity etc.
Here is photo of pores of tinder fungus or Fomes fomentarius:

UPD
With Mathematica I extracted the coordinates of the pores and made Voronoi tessellation:

Pore distribution is neither hexagonal packing nor purely random.
I see strange patterns like large circles.
Is it possible that some geometry experts knows what pattern is emerging in this structure?

Is this a flat surface? Pores might be more or less uniformly distributed if the surface is flat but become more spaced on 'peaks' and less spaced in 'valleys' if the surface is not flat

@Paul, almost flat

Looks like Poisson disk sampling

@lhf, yes! Just now I think about it, very similar

Have you heard about "hard-core model" ? See for example this paper

@JeanMarie, wow, "extended" hardcore method  picture looks almost identical!
